# springboot maven running as init.d service on linux not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc, maven-plugin

I have maven spring-boot application running as an init.d service on ec2 instance - it is working fine in the lower-level environment but when I do the same on prod instance I am getting **"Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from /path/application.war**. I have tried all possible google solutions but nothing helped to resolve as it is working at the lower level and all configs and versions are the same on both instances. attaching maven build block below. **when I unzip the war I see the main-class and start-class in manifest file**.

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>

                    <executable>true</executable>                   

                    <profiles>dev</profiles>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug
                        -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: If I understand this right, init.d is invoking maven to run a spring boot app. This may not be the way you want to run programs in production anyway. Read section 64.2.1  here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

Comment: hello martin, I followed all steps in that doc and still, I am getting the same issue